# Generating unique random values with SecureRandom

Tags: kotlin, secure-random

i'm currently implementing a secret sharing scheme.(shamir)
In order to generate some secret shares, I need to generate some random numbers within a range. FOr this purpose, I have this very simple code:

```
val sharesPRG = SecureRandom()
fun generateShares(k :Int): List<Pair<BigDecimal,BigDecimal>> {
 val xs = IntArray(k){ i  -> sharesPRG.nextInt(5)}
 return xs
 }
```

I have left out the part that actually creates the shares as coordinates, just to make it reproduceable, and picked an arbitrarily small bound of 5.
My problem is that I of course need these shares to be unique, it doesnt make sense to have shares that are the same.
So would it be possible for the Securerandom.nextint to not return a value that it has already returned?
Of course I could do some logic where I was checking for duplicates, but I really thought there should be something more elegant

Comment: Off course it is possible for `Securerandom.nextint` to return a value that it has already returned. Wouldn't be very random otherwise.

Comment: yes, and I am asking if there is a nice way to avoid those numbers

Comment: if your `k` is not too large you can keep adding random values to a set until it reaches size `k`

Comment: ah yes, thats a nice idea. Will have to let go of the nice array initializer then

Comment: You can then use the set as the source material to your list of pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `k` is not too large you can keep adding random values to a set until it reaches size `k`:

```kotlin
fun generateMaterial(k: Int): Set<Int> = mutableSetOf<Int>().also {
    while (it.size < k) {
        it.add(sharesPRG.nextInt(50))
    }
}
```

You can then use the set as the source material to your list of pairs (`k` needs to be even):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val pairList = generateMaterial(10).windowed(2, 2).map { it[0] to it[1] }
    println(pairList)
}
```